# 404 Error while saving data to mongoDb from node.js & express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

im currently trying to save some data from Bootstrap input fields into my mongoDB database but i always get the error `insertMovie:1 POST http://localhost:3000/insertMovie 404 (Not Found)`. I tried to change the Routes but i cant find my mistake. My Schema is in a file called movie.js.

I Feel like i dont really get the Route thing of express, im very new at this.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <form method="post" action="/insertMovie">
            <h1 class="text-center pt-5">Neuen Film anlegen</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Titel</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Titel eingeben"
                name="title"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Beschreibung</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Beschreibung eingeben"
                name="description"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Startdatum</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Startdatum eingeben"
                name="start"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Aktuell laufend</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Beschreibung eingeben"
                name="currentlyRunning"
              />
            </div>

            <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

movies.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require("../models/movie");


router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find();
    res.json(movies);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});


router.post("/insertMovie", async (req, res) => {
  const movie = new Movie({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    start: req.body.start
  });

  try {
    const savedMovie = await movie.save();
    res.json(savedMovie);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv/config");

//Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

//Import Routes
const moviesRoute = require("./routes/movies");
app.use("/movies", moviesRoute);

//  include a static file serving middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

// Get all Data
app.get("/data", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile("index.html");
});

// Insert new Movie
app.get("/insertMovie", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/insert.html");
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with your movie routes. With the way you set it up, your endpoint is actually:

```
localhost:3000/movies/insertMovie
```

but you are using:

```
localhost:3000/insertMovie
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to `router.post("/movies/insertMovie", async (req, res) `but now i get `Cannot POST /movies/insertMovie`

Comment: whats the full url?

Comment: @DominiKK. don't change your route url,  Alex meant that you should use this endpoint to create movie: localhost:3000/movies/insertMovie

Comment: When i pass the values via postman on `localhost:3000/movies/insertMovie ` it works fine and the data gets passed in my DB. But when i try it with submitting my bootstrap form i get this: ```{"message":{"errors":{"title":{"message":"Path `title` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"message":"Path `title` is required.","type":"required","path":"title"},"kind":"required","path":"title"},"description":{"message":"Path `description` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"message":"Path `description` is required.","type":"required","path":"description"}...```

Comment: After adding the `app.use(express.urlencoded());` middleware it works fine now.

Comment: Good to hear it is working! Please mark it as the right answer :)